# Is there a clean way to create offset branches in gitdags?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, git, gitdags

Julien Cretel created the elegant [gitdags](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags/wiki) package for easily generating educational git graphs, which I'm currently using to create educational and reference materials for my team.

When discussing branching in some context, I like to add a “kink” to the graph to visually reinforce the idea that a branch represents a line of development and that other work might continue concurrently

[image: Git graph with branch “kink”]

Is there a clean way to tell gitdags/TikZ to offset a node vertically like this?

Comment: Perhaps add a tag for gitdags? If it doesn't exist, it'd be great to create one for it :)

Comment: @cmhuges I tried but I don't have the reputation :}

Comment: No problem :) done! your question is the first to be tagged with `gitdags` :) :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as "cleaner" (and I also don't know the `gitdags` package) but anyway:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{gitdags}
\tikzgraphsset{%
  nudge/.style={/tikz/shift={#1}},
  nudge down/.style={nudge=(270:#1)},
  nudge down/.default=1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\gitDAG[grow right sep = 2em]{
  {[nodes=placeholder commits] "..."}  -- A -- B -- C -- 
  {[nudge down]
    D -- E;
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Yes, your solution is cleaner than mine: it lets us express our actual intent, rather than tricking TikZ with an invisible node hack. Thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

My current solution, used to generate the graph in the question, is to create an invisible node along the master branch, which forces the node `D` to the next row:

```
\gitDAG[grow right sep = 2em]{
  {[nodes=placeholder commits] "..." } -- A -- B -- C -- {
    "" [placeholder];
    D [>opacity=0.75] -- E;
  }
};
```

The `"" [placeholder];` bit creates the invisible node after `C` along the master branch; `D` represents a parallel line of development and therefore is vertically aligned with the invisible node.

This trick gets the job done but feels very hackish, especially since we have to reset the edge opacity when we are done (`[>opacity=0.75]`). Without this reset, nodes `D` and `E` will be rendered but their edges will not.